# Elasticsearch manipulate _score on function output

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following sample JSON

```
[{"field_1" "abc",
 "field_2": 2
 "field_3" "some more text"
},
{"field_1" "xyz",
 "field_2": 4
 "field_3" "some more text"
}]
```

I have written my custom script to give output as per field_2 value

```
"if {(doc['field_2'] < 3) { return 1.2;} else if if {(doc['field_2'] < 5) { return 1.4;} else {return 1;}"
```

Now I wanted to multiply _score with the return output of my script.

```
GET my_index/_search?
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{"Must"{....}
            }
   },
    "_source":"*",
   ,{"script_field":{
          "scrore_factor":{
                     "script":{
                            "lang":"painless",
                             "source":"""if {(doc['field_2'] < 3) { return 1.2;} else if if {(doc['field_2'] < 5) { return 1.4;} else {return 1;}"""
                     }
           } 
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that? I tried to multiply with _score but it is not parsing my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_score` is [not available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-field-context.html) inside of `script_fields`.

You can use a `function_score` query though. Your example if full of syntactic typos, plus there's no attribute called `field` in your example so I'm taking the only numeric field -- `field2`:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "script_score": {
                  "script": "def factor; if (doc['field_2'].value < 3) { factor = 1.2; } else if (doc['field_2'].value < 5) { factor = 1.4 } else { factor = 1 } return _score * factor"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joe for your reply.
[also edited my typos]
The query worked for me. One thing I did not get is When I compared the result with the changed script as "_score * 1", I was expecting the score will increase/decrease by "factor" times. but it is not. Is there any reason behind it?
Regards
Rachana J

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure what you mean -- can you share the full query/queries and pinpoint where you think the query is failing?

Comment: Thank you Joe, Changed my nested query, and started working perfectly.

Comment: Nice. Hey, I'm writing a handbook full of solutions like this. You can [join the waiting list](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) and let me know what else you'd like to learn about.